# Calling nested indexing macros

Tags: macros, memoir, indexing, nesting

Here is my simplified document sample which is failing with the errors mentioned in the comments.
I tried to enclose the nested macro with `{` and `}` and it didn't work, same with enclosing it with `\csname` and `\endcsname`. Could you please help me, how to nest indexing macros.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcounter{pqrC}
\newcommand{\pqr}[1]
{%
  \stepcounter{pqrC}%
  #1%
  \index{PQR!\thepqrC. #1}%
}%

\newcounter{xyzC}
\newcommand{\xyz}[1]
{%
  \stepcounter{xyzC}%
  #1%
  \index{XYZ!\thexyzC. #1}%
}%

\newcommand{\x}[1]{#1\index{X!#1}}
\newcommand{\y}[1]{#1\index{Y!#1}}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\xyz{Some text here!}\\
\pqr{Some other text here!}\\
\xyz{\pqr{Related to pqr} and also xyz}\\ % ERROR: Missing \endcsname inserted.

More text asldfjasdlf adlsfkja fasldfk ja\\
asldfkjasdlfkajsdlf adslfkasjdf\\

\x{sldkf \y{dlfkj}} % ERROR: Use of \@index doesn't match its definition.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nested index commands does not make any sense. Why do you want to index an item from within the index?

Comment: I am using  `xyz` macro to index the sentence and if the same sentence has a word, I want to index using `pqr`.

Comment: That is not what I mean, conceptually, `\index{... \index{...}...} ` would execute the inner index command as part of the index entry in the index it self, thus not making any sense. So attempting to make shortcuts for something like is is really asking for trouble

Comment: So the only way would be something like this: `\xyz{Sentence with keyword, more text text text text}\index{keyword}`?

Comment: Something like that, though if you are unlucky you may end up with the keyword index being on the wrong page (which is why one normale does not index sentences)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your macros you can use an `\if..`-switch (with its `\..true`/`\..false`-commands) as a flag for denoting whether the argument of the macro in question is processed as part of an argument of an `\index`-command which in turn was "launched" by one of your macros.

Vice versa, have `\index`-commands executed and counters stepped only if the macro which shall carry out these things is *not* called as part of an argument of such an `\index`-command. ;-)

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifnotindexarg
\global\notindexargtrue
\newcommand\IfNotWithinIndexArgGroupDoWithinIndexArgGroup[1]{%
  \romannumeral0%
  \ifnotindexarg\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {\@firstofone{\expandafter} \@firstofone}%
  {\@firstofone{\expandafter} \@gobble}%
  {\begingroup\notindexargfalse#1\endgroup}%
}%
\makeatother


\newcounter{pqrC}%
\newcommand{\pqr}[1]{%
  #1%
  \IfNotWithinIndexArgGroupDoWithinIndexArgGroup{%
     \stepcounter{pqrC}%
     \index{PQR!\thepqrC. #1}%
  }%
}%

\newcounter{xyzC}%
\newcommand{\xyz}[1]{%
  #1%
  \IfNotWithinIndexArgGroupDoWithinIndexArgGroup{%
    \stepcounter{xyzC}%
    \index{XYZ!\thexyzC. #1}%
  }%
}%

\newcommand{\x}[1]{#1\IfNotWithinIndexArgGroupDoWithinIndexArgGroup{\index{X!#1}}}%
\newcommand{\y}[1]{#1\IfNotWithinIndexArgGroupDoWithinIndexArgGroup{\index{Y!#1}}}%

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\xyz{Some text here!}\\
\pqr{Some other text here!}\\
\xyz{\pqr{Related to pqr} and also xyz}\\

More text asldfjasdlf adlsfkja fasldfk ja\\
asldfkjasdlfkajsdlf adslfkasjdf\\

\x{sldkf \y{dlfkj}}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

The example above yields the following index - I hope this is what you have in mind:

[image]

---

One more level of automatizing could be:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifnotindexarg
\global\notindexargtrue
%\mygenericindexsubentry{<main-entry>}{<name of counter or emptiness>}{<sub-entry>}
% (Be aware that you cannot use \mygenericindexsubentry with 
%  the nameless counter.;-) )
\newcommand\mygenericindexsubentry[3]{%
  #3%
  \ifnotindexarg\expandafter\@firstofone\else\expandafter\@gobble\fi
  {%
    \begingroup
    \notindexargfalse
    \ifx\relax#2\relax
      \index{#1!#3}%
    \else
      \stepcounter{#2}%
      \index{#1!\csname the#2\endcsname. #3}%
    \fi
    \endgroup
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\newcounter{pqrC}%
\newcommand{\pqr}{\mygenericindexsubentry{PQR}{pqrC}}%
\newcounter{xyzC}%
\newcommand\xyz{\mygenericindexsubentry{XYZ}{xyzC}}%
\newcommand{\x}{\mygenericindexsubentry{X}{}}%
\newcommand{\y}{\mygenericindexsubentry{Y}{}}%

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\xyz{Some text here!}\\
\pqr{Some other text here!}\\
\xyz{\pqr{Related to pqr} and also xyz}\\

More text asldfjasdlf adlsfkja fasldfk ja\\
asldfkjasdlfkajsdlf adslfkasjdf\\

\x{sldkf \y{dlfkj}}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

The output is the same as with the first example.

---

By the way:

If you don't want to waste count-registers, you can use macros and routines for expandable incrementing.

There are Heiko Oberdiek's packages [intcalc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/intcalc) and [bigintcalc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bigintcalc).
In case eTeX extensions are available, there is also `\numexpr`.

Below I fiddled something together myself which does without additional packages and without eTeX extensions.

```
\makeatletter
%%//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
%% SECTION EXPANDABLE INCREMENTING OF NATURAL NUMBER FORMED BY A SEQUENCE OF
%% EXPLICIT CATCODE-12-CHARACTER-TOKENS FROM THE SET {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
%%
%% \UD@increment{<natural number k as sequence of explicit catcode-12-character-
%%               tokens from the set 0123456789>}
%% ->
%% <natural number (k+1) as sequence of explicit catcode-12-character-tokens
%%  from the set 0123456789>
%%
%% Emptiness is interpreted as "0".
%%
%% Due to \romannumeral0-expansion the result is delivered after 
%% two expansion-steps.
%%..............................................................................
%% Examples: \UD@increment{999} -> 1000
%%           \UD@increment{0} -> 1
%%           \UD@increment{} -> 1
%%==============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@increment[1]{%
  % #1 = digit sequence to increment.
  \romannumeral0%
  % Start the loop for reversing the digit-sequence so that less significant
  % digits are at the beginning and not at the end of the digit sequence; when
  % reversing is done, apply \UD@incrementfork{} and a terminating \relax to
  % start replacing least significant digits by digits whose value is larger
  % by 1:
  \UD@incrementreverse{\UD@incrementfork{}}{\relax}{}#1\relax
}%
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Reverse digit sequence and prepend and append tokens afterwards:
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@incrementreverse[4]{%
  % #1 = tokens to prepend to reversed digit sequence.
  % #2 = tokens to append to reversed digit sequence.
  % #3 = digit sequence reversed so far.
  % #4 = first digit of remaining digit sequence to reverse.
  \ifx\relax#4%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {#1#3#2}{\UD@incrementreverse{#1}{#2}{#4#3}}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@incrementselect{}%
\long\def\UD@incrementselect#10123456789\relax#2#3!!{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@incrementfork[2]{%
  % #1 = carry-zeros collected so far
  % #2 = to-be incremented first digit/least significant digit of digit sequence
  \UD@incrementselect
  #2123456789\relax{\UD@incrementreverse{ }{}{}#11}%<-this means the current
                                                  %   least significant digit is
                                                  %   0 and to be replaced by 1.
  0#223456789\relax{\UD@incrementreverse{ }{}{}#12}%<-this means the current
                                                  %   least significant digit is
                                                  %   1 and to be replaced by 2.
  01#23456789\relax{\UD@incrementreverse{ }{}{}#13}%<-this means the current
                                                  %   least significant digit is
                                                  %   2 and to be replaced by 3.
  012#2456789\relax{\UD@incrementreverse{ }{}{}#14}%<-this means the current
                                                  %   least significant digit is
                                                  %   3 and to be replaced by 4.
  0123#256789\relax{\UD@incrementreverse{ }{}{}#15}%<-this means the current
                                                  %   least significant digit is
                                                  %   4 and to be replaced by 5.
  01234#26789\relax{\UD@incrementreverse{ }{}{}#16}%<-this means the current
                                                  %   least significant digit is
                                                  %   5 and to be replaced by 6.
  012345#2789\relax{\UD@incrementreverse{ }{}{}#17}%<-this means the current
                                                  %   least significant digit is
                                                  %   6 and to be replaced by 7.
  0123456#289\relax{\UD@incrementreverse{ }{}{}#18}%<-this means the current
                                                  %   least significant digit is
                                                  %   7 and to be replaced by 8.
  01234567#29\relax{\UD@incrementreverse{ }{}{}#19}%<-this means the current
                                                  %   least significant digit is
                                                  %   8 and to be replaced by 9.
  012345678#2\relax{\UD@incrementfork{#10}}%       <- this means the current
                                           %          least significant digit is
                                           %          9 and to be replaced by 0,
                                           %          which will be a carry-zero
                                           %          , and the next digit needs
                                           %          to be incremented.
  0123456789#2{\UD@incrementreverse{ }{}{}#11\relax}%<-this means the natural
                                                    % number to increment
                                                    % consisted of digits "9" 
                                                    % only and the terminating
                                                    % \relax was encountered.
  0123456789\relax{\UD@incrementreverse{ }{}{}#11#2}%<- this should not happen
                                                 %    as it means there is a
                                                 %    non-digit.
  !!%
}%
%%
%% EOF SECTION EXPANDABLE INCREMENTING OF NATURAL NUMBER FORMED BY A SEQUENCE OF
%%     EXPLICIT CATCODE-12-CHARACTER-TOKENS FROM THE SET {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
%%//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
\makeatother    

\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifnotindexarg
\global\notindexargtrue
%\mygenericindexsubentry{<main-entry>}{<counter-macro or emptiness>}{<sub-entry>}
\newcommand\mygenericindexsubentry[3]{%
  #3%
  \ifnotindexarg\expandafter\@firstofone\else\expandafter\@gobble\fi
  {%
    \begingroup
    \notindexargfalse
    \ifx\relax#2\relax
      \index{#1!#3}%
    \else
      \xdef#2{\expandafter\UD@increment\expandafter{#2}}%
      \index{#1!\@arabic{#2 }. #3}%
    \fi
    \endgroup
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand{\pqrC}{0}%
\newcommand{\pqr}{\mygenericindexsubentry{PQR}{\pqrC}}%
\newcommand{\xyzC}{0}%
\newcommand\xyz{\mygenericindexsubentry{XYZ}{\xyzC}}%
\newcommand{\x}{\mygenericindexsubentry{X}{}}%
\newcommand{\y}{\mygenericindexsubentry{Y}{}}%

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\xyz{Some text here!}\\
\pqr{Some other text here!}\\
\xyz{\pqr{Related to pqr} and also xyz}\\

More text asldfjasdlf adlsfkja fasldfk ja\\
asldfkjasdlfkajsdlf adslfkasjdf\\

\x{sldkf \y{dlfkj}}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

The output is the same as with the first example.

Comment: Perfect! This is something what I was looking forward :)